# How to generate UserID via SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I would like to generate userID, logic is, UserID is combination of FirstName and LastName. if userID is already exists then add 1 after FirstName and LastName.

for ex:

users John Doe's userID would be JohnDoe.

if another John Doe joins company then UserID should be JohnDoe1 and so on.

the case statement i am using to achieve this is, below.

```
Select distinct case
when lower(a.First_Name) || lower(a.Last_Name) = b.Name then a.First_Name || a.Last_Name || 1
when lower(a.First_Name) || lower(a.Last_Name) || 1 = b.Name then a.First_Name || a.Last_Name || 2

else a.first_name || a.last_name
end as user_id from Users a, accounts b

where a.unique_id = '12345' (This is matching key from table B)
```

In my table I already have userID JohnDoe and JohnDoe1.

and output I am getting of above query is,

JohnDoe
JohnDoe1
JohnDoe2

How do i only get JohnDoe2 as an output.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that might work in Oracle:

```
WITH oldnames AS (
    SELECT 'JohnDoe' AS user_id, 'John' AS fname, 'Doe' AS lname
      FROM dual
     UNION
    SELECT 'JohnDoe1' AS user_id, 'John' AS fname, 'Doe' AS lname FROM dual
     UNION
    SELECT 'MaxHeadroom' AS user_id, 'Max' AS fname, 'Headroom' AS lname FROM dual
), newnames AS (
    SELECT 'John' AS fname, 'Doe' AS lname FROM dual
     UNION
    SELECT 'Max' AS fname, 'Headroom' AS lname FROM dual
     UNION
    SELECT 'Mark' AS fname, 'Twain' AS lname FROM dual
)
SELECT n1.fname, n1.lname, MAX(n2.user_id)
     , n1.fname || n1.lname ||
       CASE WHEN MAX(n2.user_id) IS NOT NULL THEN TO_CHAR(COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(MAX(REGEXP_SUBSTR(n2.user_id, '\d+$'))), 0) + 1) END
  FROM newnames n1, oldnames n2
 WHERE n1.fname = n2.fname(+)
   AND n1.lname = n2.lname(+)
 GROUP BY n1.fname, n1.lname
```

Here I'm assuming that you have a table in which you're storing user IDs along with first name and last name. That's what I've called `oldnames` in the query above, with `newnames` being the table of users for whom you want to generate IDs.